# Safari14アップデートでWebGL+Leafletが動かない

Tags: javascript, safari, leaflet

Safariを14にアップデートしたら今まで閲覧していたウェブアプリケーションが動かなくなりました（13.1.2から14.0）。アプリケーションはウェブ地図（Leaflet）とWebGLを組み合わせて実現しているCS立体図という地形表現ソフトです。
https://frogcat.github.io/csmap/
アップデート後、アプリケーションの初期表示が出来たり出来なかったり、出来たとしてもすごく時間がかかり、また地図のドラッグや拡大縮小が出来なくなりました。ChromeやFirefoxでは動作します。
似たような仕組み（WebGL+Leaflet）のアプリケーション開発を考えていたため、自分の開発の際の参考にさせていただきたく、問題点や対処法等を教えて下さいますと助かります。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

ここから追記
コンソールにエラーの出力はありません。インスペクタのグラフィックスでWebGLで使用中のCanvasには描画されており、それを更新してから地図画面を操作するとブラウザに絵が表示されます。以後も同様です。一瞬画面が描き変わるも期待した絵柄でなく、インスペクタで同様の操作後に地図画面を操作すると正しい絵が表示されます。

Comment: コンソールに関連してそうなメッセージはないですか？

Comment: コンソールで何もエラーが出ないので困っています。ただ、インスペクタのグラフィックの部分でWebGLで描画された絵が表示されており、それを更新して再度ブラウザで操作すると画面が書き換わる状況です。